# SimpleSchema and MongoDB Nested Arrays in Arrays

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

I am using SimpleSchema with Meteor for Structuring the Database Entries.

The problem is, I have an array of arrays of objects (These data is displayed inside of an HTML table) and need to update single cells.

My Schema looks like: (Coffeescript)

```
drags:
    type: [[Object]]
    label: "The correct assignment of drop values"
    optional: true
    blackbox: true
"drags.$":
    type: [Object]
    label: "Row of the Table"
    blackbox: true
"drags.$.$":
    type: Object
    label: "Cell of the Table"
"drags.$.$._id":
    type: String
    label: "Unique Id of Draggable"
    optional: true
"drags.$.$.text":
    type: String
    label: "Text of Draggable"
    optional: true
"drags.$.$.fixed":
    type: Boolean
    label: "Is this Draggable Fixed to the correct spot"
    optional: true
"drags.$.$.color":
    type: String
    label: "Color of Draggable"
    optional: true
```

My Database call to update a specific cell is:

```
db.update({_id:"some-id"},{$set: {"drags.1.2.fixed":true}})
```

This call throws this error:

```
Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator
```

Comment: Try adding `blackbox: true` to the `"drags.$.$.fixed"` field in the schema?

Comment: that does not help and how should it? "drags.$.$.fixed" is boolean, so that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always easier with simple-schema to define the schema for each tier separately and them nest them. In your case:

```
drags: 
  type: [row]
  label: "The correct assignment of drop values"
  optional: true
  blackbox: true

row:
  type: [cell]
```

Then define your cell properties. Normally if you define an object as being `blackbox` there's no point in defining its individual properties. You've got one required field at the cell level but above that you're saying it's blackbox.